# Search for untagged ways in overpass-turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Is there  a way to search for untagged ways that are not part of a multi-polygon relation using [overpass-turbo.eu](http://overpass-turbo.eu)?  I am trying to locate all ways in my county that were not tagged (i.e. untagged highways, untagged buildings, pools, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there's also a Geofabrik Tool available to find ways without tags, called [OSM Inspector](http://tools.geofabrik.de/osmi/). The respective analysis can be found in the *tagging* view as *ways without tags* (just in case someone wonders, why overpass turbo comes into play for this).

Back to the question: Find all ways in a bbox and remove all ways with any tag will give you the desired result:

```
((way({{bbox}}); - way({{bbox}})[~"."~"."];);>;);
out meta;
```

Link to overpass turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/6WF

Edit: OP was actually looking for ways without tags, not belonging to relations (but didn't mention that in the first place). For this use case, please try the following:

```
(way({{bbox}}); - way({{bbox}})[~"."~"."];)->.w1;
rel(bw.w1);way(r)->.w2;
(.w1; - .w2;);
(._; >;);
out meta;
```

Overpass Turbo Link: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/6WH

Since version 0.7.54 there's also the following option:

```
way({{bbox}})(if:count_tags()==0)->.w1;
rel(bw.w1);way(r)->.w2;
(.w1; - .w2;);
(._; >;);
out meta;
```

Comment: this works but also returns all multi polygon relations.  I only want untagged ways that are not multi polygon relations either.

Comment: yes I am looking for only ways that have no relations or keys:values.

Comment: It works! I tried it in some of my mapping areas and found some data I'd messed up.  But yes actually OSM inspector is a better tool for mappers to use for finding these bugs (if you don't need the data from Overpass)  OSM Inspector has a "ways without tags" tickbox e.g. here in London: http://tools.geofabrik.de/osmi/?view=tagging&lon=-0.12399&lat=51.51339&zoom=12&overlays=ways_without_tags